# Port closed even when I port forwarded

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, portforwarding, dmz

I want to make server (for multiplayer game), but I can't connect to my pc through my public IP address. 
My server is programmed in Java like this:

```
    int port =  60000;
    int client_num = 0;
    ClientHandler clientHandler;

    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {

        System.out.println("Server is listening on port " + port);
        while (true) {
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

            System.out.println("New client connected: "+client);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Server exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Client is programmed in javascript like this(I am using websockets):

```
    var websocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://127.0.0.1:60000');

    websocket.onopen = function () {
      $('h1').css('color', 'green');
      websocket.send("Hello");
      $('h1').css('color', 'purple');
    };
```

You can see, that I use the same port (60 000) in both-server and client. In client where I write IP address (ws://127.0.0.1) I can write localhost(127.0.0.1) or my private ip (192.168.0.100) - AND IT WORKS! But when I write there my public ip (something like 91.***.***.***), it dont work and server dont write message "New client connected:" (like in case of local host do)... So I thought that problem is in port forwarding. But I tried to port forward, as you can see in image:
[image: port forwarding on my router]

But it still don't work. I also tried to use DMZ in my router. Same results. I also tried to turn off firewall and web shield of my anitivirus. Again same result...Even if i try to check if my port 60 000 is open with some online test (https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) it say that my port is closed...So why it don't work?
I have found out, that even if I turn on Apache which listen on ports 80 and 443, tools for checking open ports also show me this ports (80 and 443) as closed (even when I turn DMZ on my router)...WHY?
Note: I am sure, that i use right local IP for setting up port forwarding and DMZ, I use IP which give me ipconfig(and also as I already wrote - client-server communication works when I use this local address (192.168.0.100) of my pc where server runs...) 
Please help me! :)

Comment: Question: after you defined that port forwarding rule, did you save and restart the router?

Comment: I clicked on save settings. I tried to reboot device, but it change all local IP addresses, so my port forwarding rules are no valid then...So I can't reboot device, only save settings. Any more suggestions?

Comment: You need to give your PC a fixed address in the DHCP based on its MAC address or configure it with a static IP and exclude that IP from DHCP. Then you'll be able to reboot the router. BTW, this question is off-topic for StackOverflow, because it's a question about configuration, not about programming.

Comment: Ok, when i reboot device again, it gives me same IP (even if I don't give my PC fixed address), so the port forwarding rules are right...but it still don't works...Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is about networking and network routing. Try to connect to your server from the outside of your local network. Somewhere from internet. Buy a VPS or ask your friend. First of all you can check your port is opened using `nmap`. If it were opened you are able to connect to your server. Otherwise it might be your D-LINK problem. I see you have 22 port forwarding already. When I used D-LINK DIR-600 router I have similar issue - port was adjusted correctly but I was not able to connect via opened port. And I could fix this issue only by using DD-WRT - unofficial firmware.